# Stciky header and nested tables

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, sticky

I have a nested table layout (legacy code) that implements `sticky header` using `jquery`. Currently there are 2 tables, `maintable` and `stickytable(header)`. The columns doesn't align between the two tables.The code is dynamically generated and hence I can't dictate `column width`. In addition, both tables have several `nested tables` which makes it even more complicated. Is there any way I can make a section of the table `stick` without having 2 separate tables?

```
<table style="position:relative;" id="maintable" width="1295">
<tr>
  <td colspan="21">
    <div id="stickyheading">
      <table width="1295" id="stickytable">  -- this table has its own layout
       <tr>
             ....... (more <td> elements)
       </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
     ---------- table data (inherits maintable layout and hence columns dont align with stickytable) ----------------
   <tr valign="top">
    <td nowrap  height="15"></td>
    <td nowrap  colspan="3">
      <table width=219>
        <tr> <td>.....
      </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This code works but with alignment issues (sticky header works as well).

I moved the `div` element into the `stickytable` to group the header content and make it sticky but failed.

```
<table style="position:relative;" id="maintable" width="1295">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="21">
   <table width="1295" id="stickytable">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="21">
      <div id="stickyheading"> ---------this breaks sticky header functionality
        <tr>
         ....... (more <td> elements)
        </tr>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   ----- table data goes here ------

</table> -- stickytable ends here 
</tr>
</table>  --main table ends here
```

How do I make `stickyheader` using a single table and `div` element?
For some reason, the `div` element doesn't work inside `stickytable` but works under `maintable`. Am I missing something?

[Jfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6qobpf5/12/)

Comment: How about creating a fiddle with your sticky header and a few sample rows of mock data. I have a few ideas for you but need to tinker with your "real world" situation.

Comment: @Adrianopolis Thanks for the response. I may have to do lot of code refactor to remove company data. It might take some time, but I will try.

Comment: @Adrianopolis Sorry, I was away from this project for a while, now I have been re-assigned to this issue. Please check the updated jfiddle demo link. Thanks!